# How can I perform grouping on Solr search results in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, solr

The official [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.misc.group) provides the following example (slightly simplified here) for grouping results from a Solr query:

```
Field field = new SimpleField("popularity");
Query query = new SimpleQuery("inStock:true");

SimpleQuery groupQuery = new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria("*:*"));
GroupOptions groupOptions = new GroupOptions()
    .addGroupByField(field)
    .addGroupByQuery(query);
groupQuery.setGroupOptions(groupOptions);

GroupPage<Product> page = solrTemplate.queryForGroupPage("collection-1", query, Product.class);
```

However, when I try this, it ignores the search conditions (`inStock:true`) and just performs the grouping on all results (`"*:*"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things about this example I had to modify to get it working. First of all, as you may have noticed, the argument `query` should actually be `groupQuery` in the `queryForGroupPage` call. I also removed the `Query` and put the actual search conditions in `groupQuery`. The working version is as follows, where `groupByField` is a `SimpleField`:

```
SimpleQuery groupQuery = new SimpleQuery(conditions);

GroupOptions groupOptions = new GroupOptions()
        .addGroupByField(groupByField);

groupQuery.setGroupOptions(groupOptions);

return solrTemplate.queryForGroupPage(groupQuery, YourObjectHere.class);
```